# How to place a landscape table on a portrait page without clearing the current page?

Tags: tables, landscape

Following the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19017/how-to-place-a-table-on-a-new-page-with-landscape-orientation-without-clearing-t/453774?noredirect=1#comment1141155_453774

I would like to enter a landscape oriented table inside a portrait page without the table to be floating. Since, if it remains floating it drops in another page. I used the code of the attached link:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
    \usepackage{fullpage}  % megalitara margin gia tex
    \usepackage{algorithm} % gia tis listes graph and diagram

    \usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,xparse}  %equations in curled brackets are centered
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{scalefnt}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{booktabs}

    \usepackage{afterpage}


            \begin{document}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
            \afterpage{%
                \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
                \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
                \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
                \begin{table}
                    \centering % Center table
        \resizebox{1.5\textwidth}{!}{
         \begin{threeparttable}
           \begin{tabular}{llll}
                        A & B & C & D \\


         \end{tabular}
         \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
              \small
         \item Notes:
            \end{tablenotes}
          \end{threeparttable}
        }
        \end{table}
                \end{landscape}
                \clearpage% Flush page
            }
            \end{document}
```

but the table drops in another page. Then, I tried by adding \begin{table}[H] ...\end{table} but it only resulted in dropping the table even further and leaving a blank page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Landscape table without creating new page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180954/landscape-table-without-creating-new-page)

Comment: @SLx64 - I don't think that this new posting is a duplicate, as it involves a `threeparttable` environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the tabular material to fload, don't use a `table` float object. Instead, embed the `threeparttable` environment in a `\rotatebox{90}{...}` directive, and place the whole thing inside a `center` environment.

Of course, if you don't need a caption, you should omit the `\captionof` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{fullpage}  % megalitara margin gia tex
\usepackage{algorithm} % gia tis listes graph and diagram
%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded by "mathtools" package
\usepackage{eqparbox,xparse} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % is loaded by "rotating" package
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % <-- new

\begin{document}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blahh

\begin{center}
\rotatebox{90}{%
 \begin{threeparttable}
 \captionof{table}{ble ble ble}
 \begin{tabular}{@{} *{7}{l} @{}}
   \toprule
   A & B & C & D\tnote{*} & E & F & G \\
   \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}

 \smallskip\footnotesize
 \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  Notes:
  \item[*] bli bli bli
 \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
}% end of scope of \rotatebox directive
\end{center}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blahh

\end{document}
```